# Docking form in panel and then un-dock It from same form

Tags: vb.net, forms

I open Form2 with button on Form1. With a click on another button in Form2 this form is then added as control in split container's panel of Form1. After that I close form, but split container control is still seen (my Form2). Now I want to perform opposite - to close split container control and open Form2 to normal window as before, again from same button in Form2, in this case control in split container's panel. Is this possible ?

My main purpose of this is to dock Form2 in split container and to undock It, all done from a button on Form2. Here is my code:

EDIT:

```
Public Class Form2

    Dim BtnState As Integer
    Dim frm As Form2

    Private Shared Sub DockFormToPanel(panel As Panel, frm As Form)
        frm.TopLevel = False
        frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
        frm.Visible = True
        Form1.SplitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(frm)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub UndockFormFromPanel(panel As Panel, frm As Form)
        If Not Form1.SplitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Contains(frm) Then Throw New InvalidOperationException()
        Form1.SplitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Remove(frm)
        frm.Visible = False
        frm.TopLevel = True
        frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable
        frm.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If BtnState = 0 Then
            If frm Is Nothing Then
                frm = New Form2
                AddHandler frm.FormClosed, Sub() frm = Nothing
            End If
            DockFormToPanel(Form1.SplitContainer1.Panel2, frm)
            BtnState = 1
        Else
            UndockFormFromPanel(Form1.SplitContainer1.Panel2, frm)
            BtnState = 0
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. If someone has any better solution or thinks this is not a good way to do It, please comment. Here is my final code (in Form2):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim frm As New Form2

        If Form1.DataGridView1.Visible = True Then

            Form1.DataGridView1.Visible = False
            frm.TopLevel = False
            Form1.SplitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(frm)
            frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
            frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
            frm.Show()
            Me.Close()

        Else

            Me.Parent = Nothing
            Form1.DataGridView1.Visible = True
            frm.TopLevel = True
            frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable
            frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
            frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
            frm.Show()

        End If

End Sub
```